Continous mathematical minimization algorithm / library adaptation
In my C# application, I need to run a mathematical optimization algorithm, where control values influences the state of the system, and indirectly changes measured (target) values after the state is updated. For example, there might be 3 (or more) control values which, when changed, affect 3 (or more) target values. Any change to even a single control value may change the values of all 3 target values, and their relationship is not known.
The goal of the algorithm is to find all the minima, where the controls are set to values (while staying within designated limits) that bring the target values within a desired error margin. Later another code will compare them and identify the global minima. In other cases, when it is known that only 1 minima can exist, the optimizer should terminate as soon as it identifies that minima (don't search for additional minimas). Optimization should complete in as few cycles as possible, because changing the state of the system and making measurements is very computationally intensive.
Additionally, I need to have access to the optimizer "guess" data, so it can be re-used for repeated calculations, because the system might change very slightly, and re-using partially fitting data from the previous runs could significantly speed up the process.
The issue is that I can't seem to find a continuous mathematical optimization algorithm or C# library that can be adapted to be used this way.
This is the skeleton code for the Optimizer, and a tester demonstrating how it is intended to be used. The empty Optimizer functions is where I want to plug in the algorithm or library.
public class Optimizer
{
    public List<Control> Controls { get; init; } = new();
    public List<Target> Targets { get; init; } = new();
    public List<Minima> Minimas { get; init; } = new();
    public OptimizerData Data { get; init; } = new();

    public void Optimize()
    {
        //1. Make Controls values guess and assign OptimizedValue value for each object in Controls list
        //2. Save Controls and Targets values combination to Data
        //2. If a minima is found - add it to the list of Minimas
    }

    public bool AllMinimaFound()
    {
        //returns true when there are likely no more minima to be found - used for terminating the optimizer
    }

    public class Control
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public double OptimizedValue { get; set; }
        public double MinBound { get; init; }
        public double MaxBound { get; init; }

        public Control(string name, double minBound, double maxBound)
        {
            Name = name;
            MinBound = minBound;
            MaxBound = maxBound;
        }
    }

    public class Target
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public double MeasuredValue { get; set; }
        public double TargetValue { get; init; }
        public double ErrorMargin { get; init; }

        public Target(string name, double target, double errorMargin)
        {
            Name = name;
            TargetValue = target;
            ErrorMargin = errorMargin;
        }

        public bool IsWithinMargin()
        {
            if (Math.Abs(MeasuredValue - TargetValue) < ErrorMargin) { return true; }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class Minima
    {
        public Dictionary<string, double> ControlNamesAndValues { get; init; } = new(); // Stores the name and value of each Control for this Minima
    }

    public class OptimizerData
    {
        private List<OptimizerDataPoint> DataPoints { get; init; } = new();

        public void AddDataPoint(List<Control> controls, List<Target> targets)
        {
            DataPoints.Add(new(controls, targets));
        }

        public class OptimizerDataPoint
        {
            public Dictionary<string, double> controlsNamesAndValues { get; init; } = new();
            public Dictionary<string, double> targetsNamesAndValues { get; init; } = new();

            public OptimizerDataPoint(List<Control> controls, List<Target> targets)
            {
                foreach (Control control in controls) { controlsNamesAndValues.Add(control.Name, control.OptimizedValue); }
                foreach (Target target in targets) { targetsNamesAndValues.Add(target.Name, target.MeasuredValue); }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class OptimizerTester
{
    public void OptimizeTest()
    {
        Optimizer optimizer = new();

        optimizer.Controls.Add(new("Length", -5, 5));
        optimizer.Controls.Add(new("Width", 10, 125));
        optimizer.Controls.Add(new("Height", -7, 0));

        optimizer.Targets.Add(new("Mass", 20, 0.01));
        optimizer.Targets.Add(new("SurfaceArea", 32, 0.01));
        optimizer.Targets.Add(new("BoundingBoxVolume", 150, 0.01));

        //test 1 - find all minimas
        while (!optimizer.AllMinimaFound())
        {
            optimizer.Optimize();
            SetMeasuredTargetValues(optimizer.Targets);
        }

        //test2 - find first minima and terminate
        while (optimizer.Minimas.Count < 1)
        {
            optimizer.Optimize();
            SetMeasuredTargetValues(optimizer.Targets);
        }
    }

    public void SetMeasuredTargetValues(List<Optimizer.Target> targets)
    {
        //external code - measures and sets MeasuredValue in each Target
    }
}

Can anyone help me identify the algorithm (or a library if it already exists) to make this work?

You seem to be looking for a local nonlinear solver such as Knitro or IpOpt

@fontanf, thank you for your input, IpOpt looks promising, but I looked into it, and I can't seem to understand how would I integrate it into the code I wrote above, it appears to be meant to be used in an entirely different way. If you have the time, could you explain it in a bit more depth, or maybe there is a similar example somewhere that I failed to find?

I have no idea how to use IpOpt in C#. There seems to be a C# interface on Github https://github.com/cureos/csipopt but it hasn't received any update in 10 years. You can look for alternatives available in C# with the same keywords like https://github.com/cureos/csnumerics but I have no idea what it's worth. IpOpt and Knitro are the references for this.

I wrote a wrapper around NLopt for C# that you might find interesting: https://github.com/BrannonKing/NLoptNet . There's a Nuget package for it. Read about the algorithms in NLopt before you try to use it.

@Brannon, thank you very much, this looks amazing. But I can't quite figure out, can you do multiple objective optimization with NLoptNet? Both the NLopt library and your wrapper seems to only accept a single objective function to be optimized.

@K.S. I'm sure my wrapper does not support multiple objectives. You would have to manually combine them into a single objective with weighted parts.

@Brannon thanks, that should work. What about saving/loading the "guess" data from/to the optimizer, so that if the system does not change or changes very slightly the optimizer could reuse that data to arrive at a solution in a single iteration, or fewer iterations? Is that possible through your wrapper?

@K.S. In NLoptNet, when you call the optimize method, you pass it an initial point as an array. This is your starting point (aka, the initial guess or warmstart). The array is modified by the optimize method to contain the result of the optimize call.

@Brannon Thank you, that is good enough. Last question: does this adapted library allow for putting different bounds on input variables? I know that set_lower_bounds and set_upper_bounds can be used for setting bounds for all variables, but what if I have multiple input variables with different bounds?

Never mind. Figured it out. Thanks again!
